# How to pass String to jquery image slider in design-View in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass the text to jquery image slider but i just dont know how to acheive this, Below is the Design view:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
                //want to pass text to "desc:"sometext"
               if (!window.slider) var slider = {};
               slider.data = [{ "id": "slide-img-1", "client": "nature beauty", "desc":"" }, 
               { "id": "slide-img-2", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "" },
               { "id": "slide-img-3", "client": "nature beauty", "desc": "" }];
```

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptJquery" runat="server">

<ItemTemplate>
 <a href="">
<img ID='<%#Eval("slideshowID") %>' src='<%#String.Format("../images/slideshow/{0}", Eval("imgURL"))%>' class="slide"/>
</a> 
    //want to pass this hidden field value to the above "desc" as there are three description
    // for three images , there fore I want to pass specific description to all 3 images
    <asp:HiddenField ID="desc" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("slideDesc")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I was thinking of saving the description in an array in code behind and calling that array list in the design view something like: desc:"<%=desc[0]%>"  , Is it possible and what will be correct syntax for it

Comment: can you post (if possible) all your javascript code? Specially, what is `slider`? And how are you using it after the initialization?

Comment: http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html

Comment: javascript code is a lot , if u see the above link you can get the java script code from it , I have just included their slideshow.js, Also i am using prettyCheckboxes.js on the same page

Comment: I see, move the javascript code (the one you posted, with the opening and closing <script> tag) at the end of the html file, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Also verify that `js` files you're referencing (slideshow.js, jquery, ...) are found by the browser (I suppose you already done that).

Comment: look here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FYTG2/1/

Comment: cheers mate ... thnx a lot for taking time and solving this issue , i have no idea how jquery works nad i m still learning , i just dont know why jquery looks hard to me . but surely on a learning curve , any recommendation on learning jquery , sometimes i hate uni coz they didnt even introduced javascript to us .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(!window.slider) var  slider={};
slider.data = [{ "id": "slide-img-1", "client": "nature beauty", 
          "desc": $('#slide-img-1').parent().next('input[type=hidden]').val() },
          { "id": "slide-img-2", "client": "nature beauty",
          "desc": $('#slide-img-2').parent().next('input[type=hidden]').val() },
          { "id": "slide-img-3", "client": "nature beauty",
          "desc": $('#slide-img-3').parent().next('input[type=hidden]').val() }];
</script>
```

(Place this code just before the closing `</body>`tag.)

Comment: I dunno whats happening with my page , when i use your code , my checkbox jquery is disabled and the image slider is also not working ??

Comment: As i am using this in my code too : <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('input[type=checkbox]').prettyCheckboxes({
                     checkboxWidth: 17,
                     checkboxHeight: 17, 
                     className: 'prettyCheckbox',
                     display: 'list' 
                 });
             });

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in my answer (forgot the `#` in `$('#slide-img-1')` -- all three --). Now for my answer to work, I assumed that `slide-img-1` is the id for image 1 and so on...

Comment: it still doesnt work , all the jquerys on my page are disabled now , is it because i am using 2 jqueries which are calling input[type=checkbox] as mentioned above

Comment: the page source is something like this, as you can see the value of input boxes i just want to pass that value to jquery: <a href="">

    <img ID='slide-img-1' src='../images/slideshow/c1.jpg' class="slide"/>

    </a> 

       

        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" Value='a'/>

    

     <a href="">

    <img ID='slide-img-2' src='../images/slideshow/c2.jpg' class="slide"/>

    </a>